# Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

mobclix.com has an API for integrating with facebook.com.  Is there something similar for twitter.com and other social services?  Meaning, these will look like native parts of your app?

Comment: Does anyone have a new answer to this after the iOS 5 release?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa)

Comment: Cool. Thanks.  This looks promising.

Comment: ZaBlanc - often when people are having trouble compiling MGTwitterEngine, it's because they're missing the libxml libraries.  Make sure your Build config includes a header search path for: $SDKROOT/usr/include/libxml2

Comment: This blog post (http://brandontreb.com/creating-a-twitter-client-for-osx-part-1/) by Brandon Trebitowski written in Dec 2010 describes the installation process very well - in step 10 under "Building MGTwitterEngine" you can download a link to his organised version of the source code.

Comment: I don't recommend this library. So much pain.

Comment: @geraldKaszuba what do you recommend? thanks

Comment: MGTwitterEngine is terrible. It has no real infrastructure for logging in via OAuth.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios

Answer (score 8):

There is now a built-in [Twitter API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html) on iOS

Comment: but, it works only for iOS 5.

Comment: added in 5.0, deprecated in 6.0 - - - see instead https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios

Comment: @bshirley: it doesn't say that it's deprecated

Comment: [This version does say the TWRequest is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWRequestClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)  - it has been replaced with the [SLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from the Social.framework

Answer (score 5):

Link provided by NNN above to sharekit wasn't correct - try this one instead :

http://www.getsharekit.com/

Looks really promising and integrates with much more than Twitter!

Comment: This looks really good, because afaik MGTwitterEngine still needs a few hacks to get to work post-OAuthacalypse.

Comment: though MGTwitterEngine is painful to use, ShareKit crashes with other 3rd-party plugins (p.s. I just want to use the latest Facebook SDK, but ShareKit crashes with Facebook SDK, as ShareKit has an old version of Facebook SDK )

Answer (score 3):

Twitter's API gives you the option to have the feeds in XML or JSON format. Check their [documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com) . I don't know much about the iPhone SDK, but it surely has XML parsing.

I can't see Apple including a inbuilt API to the SDK for two reasons:

1. If they start at Twitter, they'll have to do myspace, facebook, friendfeed etc.
2. There are many Twitter apps on the app store atm. If apple released a twitter API, they'd have much more competition and wouldn't be happy with Apple.

Comment: Not expecting Apple to do it.  Hence my mention of mobclix.com's  approach for facebook.

Comment: After the release of iOS5 and it's fully integrated Twitter support, I put it to you that your prediction was wrong.

Comment: We can say right now that Apple don't care who is affected or not..! It's business. See iAd and AdMob..? We have to be updated..! It's good for developers.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/).

It supports other services like Facebook, Delicious, Tumblr and more too.

Answer (score 3):

[DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController)

Works with iOS 4 or later.

Comment: It don't work for me . There are still authorizing dialog appear , when i try to autorize app . It still stuck on authorizing dialog.

Comment: @jojas So did `DETweetComposeViewController` work or any other framework work for you. Could you share your findings. Even i am stuck with this

Comment: If you're having problems with [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController), please post a new question here on SO. We'll do our best to help you get it working.

Comment: Just what I was looking for :). Thanx @DaveBatton for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Gemmell and Craig Hockenberry, developer of Twitterific created [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa), an easy-to-use library of classes providing methods that make it extremely easy for the developer to access the Twitter API.  see 
I believe there are a few other libs out there, but it's just as easy to roll your own because like Macha says above Twitter's API gives you the option to have the feeds in XML or JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [FHSTwitterEngine](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine). Its a synchronous library, so you can get twitter data in real time. With GCD, queues, and threading, you can get the same functionality as asynchronous. I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for Twitter built into the 2.2.1 SDK. I can not comment about the 3.0 beta per NDA restrictions, but you should not expect Apple to include a service-specific API in the SDK.

Any Twitter or web service consuming feature has to be coded using the existing API calls and it is your choice to use Interface Builder to emulate the native iPhone look as close as possible.

Comment: Awesome, downvoted for stating the truth.

Comment: There, take your vote back ;-)

Comment: Looking back, I was too specific, and not helpful at all. Woops!

Answer (score 0):

for IOS 5 and more [tweet sheet](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-tweet-sheet) does the job