# Use Twitter API in iPhone

Tags: twitter

I need to use Twitter api from iPhone 3.0 (SDK 3.0). can i use it for twitpic, twitter search, Twitter account verification and twiter status update.

Please help me, if any links, code snippet on how to use.

Comment: Twitpic is an entirely separate site with its own API.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use [FHSTwitterEngine](http://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine/). Its tons less crufty than MGTwitterEngine and is a ton easier to use.