# Using the Twitter API within iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I want to integrate Twitter API into my iphone application. I have read about JSON framework with iPhone SDK 2.2. But I am new to this type of application. Can anybody please explain how to integrate this Twitter's APIs with my application and how to use it. Also tell me how to open "svn checkout http://json-framework.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ json-framework-read-only"  I have downloaded this code, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Please help me in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why has someone marked this down and not left a reason?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880771/twitter-api-for-iphone-impl , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter

Answer (score 7):

Try [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa).

Comment: ok thanks for that, but can you please tell me how to integrate it in our application.There is some License Agreement for using that.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider looking at the [Stanford iPhone programming course](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php) for some basic "how to use an API" type information.

Their in-class sample app is a low-end Twitter app that uses the JSON library, you might find that a useful example.