# how to update data to twitter from my phone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, twitter

I am creating a app that I want to have a button for the user to tell others on twitter about my APP and have them post it to their twitter account.. how can this be done im fairly new to iphone programming, but this will finish up my second app please help and thanks for all your advice concerning this matter.

Comment: Duplicate of this question, among others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has an API which you can use to send messages to twitter with.  There API is documented [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/).

Answer (score 1):

ShareKit has Twitter support and is fairly easy to implement.

http://www.getsharekit.com/