# Simplest way to implement twitter capability to iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I need to add basic twitter support to an iphone app

Does anyone know if there is a 3rd party solution like the facebook connect for twitter?

OR

if anyone knew if any of the popular Twitter iPhone apps (eg tweetie2 etc) have a custom URL scheme implemented so that it is possible to use their client to send a tweet from my app without having to implement my own mini twitter client?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweetie 2 does have [a custom URL scheme](http://developer.atebits.com/tweetie-iphone/protocol-reference/), and a protocol to allow your app to interact with it. Some Googling suggest that [other Twitter apps](http://handleopenurl.com/) do, too (though I haven't verified that info!).

Answer (score 1):

Twitter is a RESTFUL API, so use a third party REST API such as [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) and parse the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the simplest and realy working way to do it is here: http://getsharekit.com/