# connecting twitter

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone application in which i need to connect with twitter. can i do this using twiter api key? If possible how to get the twitter api key?

Comment: Try [Twitter API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) and [iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action).

Comment: Sure it's possible with the twitter api:
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/

Comment: Try using [MGTwitterEngine](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine).

Comment: This is potentially a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://apiwiki.twitter.com

Answer (score 1):

After you register your application at twitter.com/developer and get the token, its access level by default is read-only. If you want to send tweet as well, you need to change the access level to read-write and recreate your personal token.