# Integrating Twitter SDK for IOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter

I'm trying to integrate "log-in by twitter account" on my app. I've been trying a lot of external SDKs but to no avail. (TwitterAgent / Sharekit) I can't use the official twitter framework cause I'm using IOS 4.3 on xcode 3.2.6. All I want in my app is to be able to log in using his/her twitter account and get the username or user id of the twitter account that is logged in.

Any tutorials that can lead me?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, Sharekit is the best way to do it on iOS4 and up.

BUT: Have you read the instructions and sticked to them really close?
If not, read this: [Sharekit installation and usage](http://getsharekit.com/install/)

It's dead simple!!!

By the way: Why are you working on Xcode 3? Is it necessary?

EDIT:

please provide a screenshot of your compiler error like this one:
[image: gcc compiler error]

Comment: mmm, yea kinda necessary. but anyways, after adding sharekit classes, i get Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
this error after building.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248520/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-code-1-iphone).  There can be many reasons for that.  Can you copy and paste a few lines more of the error?  Therefore you have to go to the build messages or copy from debug console.  I'd - by the way - recommend you to update to Xcode 4. You can get it also for Snow Leopard, if you don't have access to the Mac App Store

Comment: thanks! i have already fixed the problem, and now, i just need to integrate twitter log in. i have already read this http://getsharekit.com/install/ but it seems im still lost on where to integrate the twitter log in. :(

Comment: @RowiePo Just init a simple UIButton, add a target method and add it as subview: `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
 target:self
 action:@selector(share)]` and than implement the share method like described under **Handling the Button Action** on the website. When your button action is _@selector(share)_ your method has to be named **share** instead of _myButtonHandlerAction_. You can copy the method from the website. Don't forget to import `#import "SHK.h"` at the top of your class. The Action Sheet is produced automatically once clicked on the b

Comment: how do you use the logging in twitter that uses OAuth for authentication and opens up a webview to login?

Comment: automatically if not already logged in, when you tap on Twitter in the actionsheet

Comment: uhm, i dont want to use the action sheet, is there anyway to call the twitter form from my button?

Comment: can be possible, but don't know a quick answer at the moment

Answer (score 0):

check this post
may help
as now almost everyone develops in iOS 5

[connecting twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645755/connecting-twitter)

n if you hav added the sharekit, import the sharekit file into the view controller where you need twitter  & import them

## import "SHKTwitter.h"

## import "Twitter/Twitter.h"

Comment: i already have a twitter api key, what i need is a working sdk for IOS 4.3 if theres any.

Comment: i got an error Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
:(