# how to get connected to twitter in iphone?

Tags: iphone

how to get connected to twitter in iphone ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Twitter on your phone, get one of several Twitter apps. If you want to talk to Twitter programmatically, they have an [API](http://twitter.com/twitterapi).

Answer (score 2):

View this tutorial: [iCodeBlog:Diving into the Twitter Stream](http://icodeblog.com/2010/05/21/diving-into-the-twitter-stream/)

Answer (score 0):

The Three20 library has a Twitter engine which works great

http://github.com/facebook/three20