# iPhone: how twitter API help to make app

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

hi i am start to develop **twitter app on iPhone**, how twitter API help to make app and how i have to use twitter API for developing application on iPhone r any platform

Comment: Please make your question specific. Twitter API is not an IDE that's gonna help you build your app, and neither will it help to greatly enhance your own app's functionality if you're not building a new twitter client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/) it covers everything, including Twitter.