# Twitter button in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, share

How do I put a Twitter button in my iOS app so the user can tweet their score?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at ShareKit: http://www.getsharekit.com/

It's pretty self explanatory, with [documentation on the website](http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/)
And it offers more than twitter, if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this question and thought I'd point out that with the upcoming iOS 5, there will be native Twitter support for every app. No technical/implementation details yet, obviously, but if you care to wait for a while you can get your hands on a native library, which will probably make your life a lot easier!

http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/11/06/09/inside_apples_ios_5_built_in_twitter_integration_makes_tweeting_a_snap.html (one source of many)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still interested, just read an awesome post on exactly this issue.  See link for a step by step guide.  He couldn't have made it any any easier :)

http://buildinternet.com/2011/10/tweet-sheet-creating-a-popup-tweet-in-ios-5/

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. It is best if an answer can stand on it's own; so please edit your post to contain the technical details. You can then add the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController)

Works with iOS 4 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Just check [this blog post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5) out for Twitter integration in iOS 5.

The advantage of using the tweet sheet is that it’s built right onto iOS, this means lots of things:

- Standard interface throughout the OS
- Automatic use of the user’s system Twitter account
- Automatic check for a tweet less than 140 characters long
- Easy image and link attachments
- Easy to program, no need to implement OAuth or connect to the Twitter backend

As you can see we have lots of advantages and incentives to use this and, being that it’s so simple, there’s no excuse not to include Twitter functionality in your applications!

Answer (score 1):

Just include the header file #import "Twitter/Twitter.h"
and add the framework Twitter.framework in the project..

and add the below lines for a button action

TWTweetComposeViewController *tweeter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [tweeter setInitialText:@"your score"];
        [self presentModalViewController:tweeter animated:YES];

That all.. ur score will be posted...

If u want to add picture use  [tweeter addImage:image ];
If u want to add url use  [tweeter addUrl:@" your url"];

Answer (score 1):

You can add an EasyTweet button to the app and where it says "Hello. This is a tweet." just add in the relevant content, ie "Just scored 42 points on YourApp.". This will be found in the ViewController.m file.