# Connecting to Twitter API

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter

How to connect to the Twitter API using Xcode?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add some more detail on what exactly you're trying to accomplish? As it stands, this is likely to get closed quickly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

Answer (score 0):

If by using XCODE you mean using Objective-C, then you can use this Twitter API: [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa).

You can also use any other C/C++ library for Twitter, or write your own (it's not **that** hard if you only want the basic stuff).

Answer (score 0):

hello hope this can help you

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-json-twitter-api/

Answer (score 0):

Matt Gemmell's MGTwitterEngine is the way to go. Simply import and use. There's a little more work to do if you need to authenticate via OAuth