# how to post on the wall of twitter from my application

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

i need to post on the wall of twitter from my application.

i found info regarding Facebook,But there is no much info regarding twitter.

is there any sdk that i need to post on the wall of twitter.

can any one please post some code or tutorial regarding this.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa) or [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone).

Comment: There is no info regarding how to post.In the above url

Comment: Twitter-OAuth actually has a Demo that shows you how to use the classes, it's actually fairly simple. When you import the correct headers, its as simple as [_engine sendUpdate:@"Tweeting something #cool!"]; It really couldnt be any simpler.

Comment: if (controller) 
  [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];
 else {
  [_engine sendUpdate: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Already Updated. %@", [NSDate date]]];
 }
this is the code in view did load... But it did n't show any screen

Comment: In Twitter-OAuth-iphone there is a sample demo example,that runs upto ligin screen only.But i did n't find and info regarding post on wall in this demo

Comment: You obviously need  a beter understanding of the Objective-C. There are many examples on the net that demonstrate how to login and post to Twitter, i gave you 2.

Answer (score 1):

Hi
You can do this using  [tweet anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin) using javascript.

[Tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/02/twitter-web-designer-and-developer-toolbox-api-and-tutorials/)

Answer (score 1):

You refer the following two URLs, You will get some idea.

http://matrixpointer.com/karl/posts/mpoauth-on-the-iphone-mpoauthmobile

Download code Here http://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth

Comment: There is no info regarding how to post.In the above url