# Twitter API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, network-programming, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

I am trying to use the Twitter API but am not looking to use OAuth/some other person's library. I would like basic code for a user name and password and than a tweet. Is this possible? I have been browsing the web for anything on this for at least 7 hours and have come up empty handed. I found one but it didn't work. Please help me with this. Thanks.

If you want to look at the code I found you can download it [here](http://www.brandonsdesigngroup.com/twitter2.zip). The problem is that it says it works but my Twitter wall doesn't reflect that. To test it just put your username and password in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Accept I said I didn't want to use oauth I just wanted to do It a basic way.

Comment: Basic auth is no longer supported. You must use OAuth, there is no other way.

Comment: What is your objection to using OAuth?  That is, by the way, the "basic way".

Comment: I don't want to use someone else's library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few libraries that makes this very easy.  Just look around.  [**MGTwitterEngine**](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa) is one such library that works great.  Also, check out [**ShareKit**](http://www.getsharekit.com/).

Comment: Plus I said I didn't want to use anyone else's libraries or use aouth. Any other ideas.

Comment: Um, aren't you required to use OAuth now with the Twitter API?  Not sure because I don't use Twitter in my app.

Comment: That was one of my questions I wasn't positive but I saw tons of examples that didn't use it.

Comment: AFAIK OAuth used to be optional, but I'm pretty sure that as of June 2010 it became mandatory.

Comment: How do I use oauth without someone elses lib. I don't want attribution.

Comment: You could write your own code?  But really, that's a huge task.  There's nothing unprofessional about attribution, lots of high-profile apps attribute libraries and other things.

Comment: I looked at some of the libraries and it had a (webpage) to log in. If you look at the pulse app on the app store it just has 2 fields and its not a website. How do you do this???

Comment: I really think they're using an OAuth library and just making it look like it's a website.  Sorry, I haven't used Pulse so I don't know what it looks like.  If you like, you can also use a different OAuth library: [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone).  You can view a nice tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/).  Not sure about whether attribution is required or not.

Comment: That is one that is a website.

Answer (score 0):

MGTwitterEngine works quite well, http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa

Also, if you saw the Apple iOS5 Keynote earlier this week you might have noticed that Twitter is built into iOS5.

If you are targeting your app to be ready for iOS5, I would recommend using the native SDK.

Comment: I was looking into it but I would like my apps to still be 4.2 compatible.

Comment: Plus I said I didn't want to use anyone else's libraries or use aouth. Any other ideas.

Comment: Problem is that it uses OAuthConsumer, which is one big memory leak.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API requires OAuth. If you only want to use username and password, you need to emulate browsing the Twitter web and authenticating. That's fragile and less clean than using OAuth code. I'm not going to bother posting details.

However, if you are planning a future release, in iOS 5 you need less than 100 lines: http://www.pastie.org/2057025

Comment: I want it to also work on ios4.2