# Twitter official SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter

Is there an official Twitter SDK for iOS? If so, where can I possibly find it?

I want to share status updates from my iPhone application.

### update:

check this [Link](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#objectivec) twitter does not has their offical sdk but they have private api's link on their website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

Comment: @stephen I think that is not an offical sdk i have check this link before asking this question

Comment: Did you read the question? They're looking for an official Twitter API. Just like you are.

Comment: but they do not found that about 2 years ago

Comment: Stack Overflow works as a wiki in this context. If the answer is no longer correct then it can be updated. The answer, however, is still correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the link,

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

Comment: Simple MGTwitter is old thing. I have given MgTwitterEngine with oAuth. Also that source code is for Xcode4.SO it will work.

Comment: +1 for for your kind help (thanks). I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried google?

Also have a look at [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

Comment: i think this is not an offical twitter Sdk for ios

Comment: I doubt whether its there for iPhone or not, but surely we have access to twitter api... http://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: i think there is not any sdk but api are there.