# Integrating facebook post request on my iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, twitter

How to put facebook and twitter post request.... so user can post to facebook and twitter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to share text/links/images on facebook/twitter from your iOS Application, you can use the ShareKit Library http://getsharekit.com/ for Twitter.
and you can follow the iOS Guide at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ for facebook integration.

Comment: great answer!  There's more Twitter / iOS information at [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

Comment: Plus you can also use http://facebook.stackoverflow.com for Facebook Dev related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I use ShareKit for social posts, maybe it will be helpful for you.

[ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/)