# How to develop twitter on iOS 5, iOS 4 and older

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

How to develop a twitter app that post images, message and link into twitter? The twitter app can run on iOS 5, iOS 4 and older. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an iPhone SDK API for twitter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757649/is-there-an-iphone-sdk-api-for-twitter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to take the shortest possible route here. If I would you I would check the [iOS SDK](http://www.addthis.com/help/ios-quickstart#.TsDqHGCTd5E) for [addthis](http://www.addthis.com/).

Its very easy to add and use. I think it supports even iOS 3.x series.

Comment: Thanks, it's usefull but I want to write native code for monitor and control my app source code. How to do it?

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/ I would check out what twitter offers. You need to use JSON to parse the twitter data (I use JSONKit, https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) AddThis is a an open source library, so you can check that out, even if you dont use it (Its MIT/Apache) if am not misstaken.

Comment: OK, I'll to try with your solution. Thanks!